# Django: PosixPath object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-settings

Before version 3.x of Django it was possible to define templates, static and media folder using `os.path`. Into `settings.py` I had this configuration:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
.
.
.
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
.
.
.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static-folder')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media-folder')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Now the settings are changed and I need to use `Path`:

```
from pathlib import Path
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

I'm following this new way but I think something is not clear for me. My new `settings.py` configuration is:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates',
        ],
.
.
.
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static-folder'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media-folder'

STATICFILES_DIRS = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

But with that configuration I see this error:

> Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in
> _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/MIO/Miosito/WebApp/backend/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> line 53, in wrapper
> fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/MIO/Miosito/WebApp/backend/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
> line 118, in inner_run
> self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/MIO/Miosito/WebApp/backend/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 392, in check
> all_issues = checks.run_checks(   File "/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/MIO/Miosito/WebApp/backend/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py",
> line 70, in run_checks
> new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)   File
> "/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/MIO/Miosito/WebApp/backend/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/checks.py",
> line 7, in check_finders
> for finder in get_finders():   File "/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/MIO/Miosito/WebApp/backend/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py",
> line 282, in get_finders
> yield get_finder(finder_path)   File "/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/MIO/Miosito/WebApp/backend/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py",
> line 295, in get_finder
> return Finder()   File "/home/maxdragonheart/DEV_FOLDER/MIO/Miosito/WebApp/backend/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py",
> line 57, in **init**
> for root in settings.STATICFILES_DIRS: TypeError: 'PosixPath' object is not iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this - `STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static',]`

Comment: @Dario How is that a comment? It's an honest attempt for an answer (which actually solves the problem...). If you think this is not a ***good*** answer, simply down-vote but don't recommend deletion